# Python and Selenium error "Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException"

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating a web automation using the Selenium library in Python language but when it comes to Username or email, I get this error(I do not get the error in the Password section). I researched in the forum but I could not find a solution. I'm new to Python and selenium so I'm waiting for your help.

Code:

```
#Get Url
browser.get('https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en')
time.sleep(5)

#Choose Username 
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('usernameForUser')
time.sleep(5)
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="username"]"}

(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

Code to ScreenShot:

[image]

An iframe code appears in Div. Could the problem be caused by this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the iframe needs to be switched to.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.top')))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Sorry, it gave an error. Code #Choose Username 

WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".top)))

time.sleep(5)

Comment: Error: File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 236, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Python\ProtonMailAçma\Protonmailac.py", line 40
    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".top)))
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: oh forgot to close it.'.top'

Comment: It worked when I typed '.top' but gave the same error in the password part. I was not getting any errors before.

Comment: Same Error: Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="password"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)

Comment: Code : #Choose Username 

WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.top')))
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('usernameForUser')
time.sleep(5)

browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('passwordForUser')

Comment: do .bottom and switch to the other iframe. There's 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wrote the code and it worked. As an example, I edited the subject. Could you please take a look? Do you think there is a correct code?

Answer (score 0):

The username textbox is inside the frame so to interact with that you need to switch frame.

```
frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
print(len(frames))

driver.switch_to.frame(0)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
username.send_keys("xyz")
```

The password textbox is not in the frame so you have to switch the control back to main page and excess the password textbox. Since password textbox takes some time to get ready to be accessed after switching from frame so use explicit wait here. Like,

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()

password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
password.send_keys("123")
```

One more thing, since the URL takes time to load, use implicitly wait instead of time.sleep().

Comment: Thank you so much. I wrote the code and it worked. As an example, I edited the subject. Could you please take a look? Do you think there is a correct code?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. If my snippet helped you, you may upvote the answer so that it helps others as well.